# A plugin to hide "we set cookies" information

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Is there any plugin that would block this annoying information displayed on majority of sites I visit?

Comment: Nice infographic [here](http://blog.silktide.com/2013/01/the-stupid-cookie-law-is-dead-at-last/). I don't know if any extensions exist for this, but you can also look and see if any userscripts are available that do what you want.

Comment: Both of the most popular Adblock extensions are able to block specific elements in a website.

Comment: In case they are JS, use NoScript

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need the extension "I don't care about cookies".

The direct link is: http://www.kiboke-studio.hr/i-dont-care-about-cookies/

It is available for Firefox, Chrome, and Opera.  The referenced website also mentions a solution for Internet Explorer.